# How can i do this curl via axios?

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

I have this curl:

```sh
curl -X 'POST' 'http://127.0.0.1/?conf%3D%7B%22flag%22%3A%20%22true%22%7D' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'v=@upload.mp4' \
  --output 'arch.zip'
```

I need to do it via axios. Now i trying like this:

```
    const fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('v', fileBuffer);

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/',
        params: {
             conf: {"flag": "true"}
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        data: fd,
    }).then(response =>console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I'm a little confuse about --output flag, how can i do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Save the response content to a file?

Comment: Yes, i want to save response content as zip

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync('my.zip', response.data)` maybe....